# Gitlab CI doesnt recognize changes from one repo (branch) in another repo

Tags: git, gitlab-ci

Issue is related with gitlab/git changes across repos.

Is it possible to create some branch in `REPO A (branch A)` and then make some change in `REPO B` and then commit and push it from `REPO A (branch A)`?

I have a project with a lot of repos like this

```
REPO A - gitlab.ci.yml
REPO B - gitlab.ci.yml
REPO C - gitlab.ci.yml
REPO D - pipeline.yml, rules.yml, etc
```

in REPOS A, B and C I have a gitlab.ci.yml files which included project from repo D, some variables and stages. In repo D I have a job denifitions, rules etc

Now My pipeline works. When I create branch from `repo A` and run pipeline gitlab.ci.yml recognize configuration from `repo D` and it works perfectly. However, I can't make any changes in REPO D when I working from `REPO A, B or C` - git doesn't recognize any changes from another repos. Is it possible?

Im expecting that I would like to make some changes in another repo (like `repo D`) from `repo A`.

Comment: In the above example, is `REPO D` added as a submodule to the other repos? And then the other repos are configured to initiate their operations when the submodule is properly cloned?

Comment: No I didnt add anything as a submodule. The configuration included only something like this:
REPO A
gitlab.ci.yml
include:
 - project: REPO D
 - file: "pipeline.yml"

Comment: If all of them are completely separate individual repositories on remote, and none of them are included in each other as a submodule, then no repository would be able to track changes of any other repositories except their own and any dependencies added as submodules.
From the given explanation, it is difficult to visualize exactly how your repositories are setup on remote and how they are operating.

Comment: How can I add submodule as reference to another repo? Command submodule add trying to copy repo. My repo already exist locally and I dont want to copy all of them. I would like set submodule to another repo without copy from remote.

Comment: Don't use submodules for this! All you need is already covered by Gitlab CI features in my answer. Submodules are painful to manage and doesn't make sense here: you're not gonna add a submodule in all of your other repos just to référence Gitlab CI configs.

Answer (score 0):

When using Gitlab CI [`include`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#include), you can specify a Git reference (branch, tag, or even a commit) with following syntax:

```yaml
include:
  - project: 'my-group/my-project'
    file: '/templates/.gitlab-ci-template.yml'
    ref: main # <---- here
```

In your case:

- create a branch in repo D
- create a branch in repo A and update the Gitlab CI `ref` in the `include` to target the branch of repo D
- once you're happy with the changes, merge and update back `ref`

You could also be using Git tags.

Comment: Hi,

Thanks for aswer but:
- My Repos A, B, and C will included only repo D. I will not mix repo A and repo B for example.
- Repo D has something like 20 KB's so it doesnt matter if I will add tihs as submodule
- and then finally - I dont want create two branches. I would like to Create one branch in repo A and make some changes in repo A and D and then push it together without any additional branches

Comment: Be sure to read all it means to use submodules then. It's a pain to use.